# Valid Inequality Example (Wolsey Example 9.3)

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, branch-and-cut, valid-inequalities

I was following Wolsey Example 9.3: Let $X = \{(x,y) \in (R^{m}_+,B^1) : \sum_{i=1}^m x_i \leq my\}$. Now consider the valid inequality $x_i \leq y$ and show that it is facet defining.

My question is why is this  a valid inequality? For example one point in $X$ may be $(x,y) = ((0,3,0),(1))$ such that $0+3+0 \leq 3\times1$, but their valid inequality removes this solution, $3 \leq 1$.

Comment: Although it is not explicitely written, I believe $x_i \le 1$.

Comment: @Joshua, Are you sure the valid inequality $x_i \leq y$ would not be $x_i \leq M*y$?

Comment: @Omidi That would makes sense to me, but it is not what is written in the book.

Comment: @Kuifje Do you know why it would be implied? Never the less, if I assumed that, the rest of the example would make sense.

Comment: @Joshua I assumed that because with such binaries, $X$ describes part of the facility location problem.

Answer (score 12):

As @Kuifje suggested, an upper bound $x_i \le 1$ was mistakenly omitted.  This omission was noted in [this errata sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20110127032208/www.core.ucl.ac.be/wolsey/correcti.htm), and it was corrected in the second edition of the book.